# foreign key in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

I have three models in a Ruby on Rails application:

1. Magazine
2. Product
3. Page

I want to use this query:

```
Magazine.find(1).products.first.pages
```

and get a page associated with appropriate product
but in page model I don't want `product_id` be my foreign key I want `number_id` be my foreign key.
number is a field in product table.
how can change foreign key? because rails work with `product_id` as foreign key for page table.
tnx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write the appropriate codes for your models.

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :pages, :through => :products
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "number"
  belongs_to :magazine
  has_many :pages, foreign_key: "product_number"

  def my_pages
    self.pages.find_all { |p| p.magazine_id == self.magazine_id}
  end  
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

You can call Magazine.first.products.first.my_pages

and it will return correct results.

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation has all the answers.  See the [options for #has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options). You probably want to specify the relationship this way:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, foreign_key: "number_id"
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
end
```

It's not totally clear to me from your question, but if the primary key for your product table isn't :id then you'll need to also specify primary_key: "number" or whatever your primary key is.

Comment: if you test this query Magazine.first.products.first.pages , you get all pages associated with number_id and ignore magazine_id !!! I want to consider both of them. for example I want above query give me exactly pages associated with product B from magazine A.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which foreign key you want to use, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-foreign_key